# unable to show googlemap api in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this [link](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/), but unable to show google map. I am searching for a specific location display with polygon lines with surround area in search location. How to display with search location with polygon lines in google map using JavaScript.

TIA